# HTML 5 File Input Options On Mobile

Tags: html, mobile

I have this input tag.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*, application/pdf" capture="camera">
```

On mobile this input goes straight to the camera, but i want it to have option where a user can select an existing file or go to the camera?

What am i missing?

Comment: Don't use `capture="camera"`?

Comment: @SLaks will that allow a user to pick a file or take a picture. Is there an example online?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do it is this: `<input type="file" accept="image/*">`
That should prompt the user to upload or use camera.

Comment: i have seen other ways where people can chose from dropbox? How is this done? Also if i want to give users to upload others documents such as pdf documents, can i just ommit the accept? image?

Comment: Unfortunately, if they want to be able to upload an arbitrary file type, you can't have it pop up the camera AFAIK. Best thing to do is have separate `<input>` elements for the two different types of file upload.